# How to compare AIC for mixed effects vs fixed effects

Tags: mixed-model, aic

I have time series data for 80 individuals and I'm trying to fit a nonlinear ODE. I am comparing the result of doing the fit separately for each individual vs. doing a mixed effects model. My approach is to use the (marginal) AICc for the mixed effects model, i.e.,

$$
mAICc=-2\log L+2(2k)+\frac{2k(2k+1)}{(N-2k-1)}
$$
where $k$ is the number of parameters to the ODE model.

For the individual fits I let:

$$
AICc=-2\log\bigg(\frac{RSS}{N}\bigg)+2nk+\frac{nk(nk+1)}{(N-nk-1)}
$$

where $n=80$ is the number of individuals and $RSS$ is the combined sum of squares for all individuals.

A reviewer told me that this second formula is somehow incorrect, but did not say how and I cannot ask as the paper was rejected.